# Array interface generic in java

Tags: java, generics

```
public class MyArrayImp<T extends Comparable<T>> implements MyArray<T> {
    private MyArrayImp[] m;
    private int i;
    private T element;

    @Override
    public T get(int i) {
        return (T) m[i].element;
    }

    @Override
    public void set(int i, T e) {
        m[i].element = e;   
    }

    etc...
```

I want to implement a generic array class having the following interface with MyArrayImp class

```
public interface MyArray<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    T get(int i);
    void set(int i, T e);
    int min();
    int max();
    int nbBetween(T e1, T e2);
}
```

finally create a class MyArrayFactory which Create and return an array of size n
public static > MyArray getMyArray(int n) { return new ...;
}

i dont want the method i only want to know how implement the class with interface and create an object from another class.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Can you clarify?

Comment: I dont understand why your members are defined as private MyArrayImp[] m;
    private int i;
    private T element; You only need to have a private T[] elements member

Answer (score 1):

I would define like this:

```
public class MyArrayImp<T extends Comparable<T>> implements MyArray<T> {
    private T[] m;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public MyArrayImp(Class<T> clazz, int size) {
        this.m = (T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, size);
    }

    @Override
    public T get(int i) {
        return m[i];
    }

    @Override
    public void set(int i, T e) {
        m[i] = e;   
    }
...etc
```